# Pass complex value to object for XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xsd

I have XSD file which was base to generate (by xsd.exe tool) C# classes for serialization. DotNetCore 3.1. Below is generated code

```
public partial class Deklaracje {
    public PozycjeSzczegolowe PozycjeSzczegolowe {get;set;}
}

public partial class PozycjeSzczegolowe {

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttibute("Bank", typeof(BankPozycjeSzczegolowe))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttibute("PodmiotNZ", typeof(PozycjeSzczegolowePodmiotNZ))]
  public object[] Items {get;set;} 
}
```

there is my serialization code to get xml

```
var myObject = ??? // <= HERE IS PROBLEM 
var data = new Declaracje
{
    PozycjeSzczegolowe = new PozycjeSzczegolowe { Items = new [] {myObject} }
}

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Deklaracje));
        xml.Serializer(xmlTextWriter, data)
    }
}
```

My problem is how to pass to **myObject** both type: **Bank** and **PodmiotNZ** objects to success XML generation

1. when I try do this by anonymous type I get "*Anonymous type cannot be serialized because don't have parameterless constructor*"
2. when I try use named class "MyClass" I get error "*My class is not expected. Use XmlInclude*", I tried to add this parameter by parital class to Declaration and PozycjeSzczegolowe classes. Alse I try to pass as extraType param to XmlSerializer constructor, but I still get this error
3. Do you have other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication181
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            Deklaracje data = new Deklaracje()
            {
                PozycjeSzczegolowe = new PozycjeSzczegolowe[]
                {
                    new BankPozycjeSzczegolowe() { name = "John"},
                    new PozycjeSzczegolowePodmiotNZ() { name = "Mary"}
                }
            };

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms,settings))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Deklaracje));
                    xml.Serialize(writer, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class Deklaracje {
       public PozycjeSzczegolowe[] PozycjeSzczegolowe {get;set;}
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(BankPozycjeSzczegolowe))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PozycjeSzczegolowePodmiotNZ))]
    public partial class PozycjeSzczegolowe {
    }
    public class BankPozycjeSzczegolowe : PozycjeSzczegolowe
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class PozycjeSzczegolowePodmiotNZ : PozycjeSzczegolowe
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```